# How to add title attribute in drop down using {html_options} in smarty 3.1

Tags: smarty

Here is my code.

**PHP CODE**

```
$smarty->assign('myOptions', array(
                            1800 => 'ABC',
                            9904 => 'DEF',
                            2003 => 'GHI')
                            );
$smarty->assign('mySelect', 9904);
```

**SMARTY CODE**

```
{html_options name=foo options=$myOptions selected=$mySelect}
```

**DESIRED HTML OUTPUT**

```
<select name="foo">
 <option value="1800" title="ABC">ABC</option>
 <option value="9904" title="DEF" selected>DEF</option>
 <option value="2003" title="GHI">GHI</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: You want to set  the title attribute for the select or for the options inside?

Comment: @Borgtex : i want to set title attribute for option.

Comment: Please clarify while adding your desired html output to your question.

Comment: @Bjoern : i have edited the question explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; not with the default html_options function at least. You can try to modify it or better create your own plugin to allow more parameters or complex arrays, but other than that, the best way to do it is generating the list of options in the template using a foreach.

Another option would be to use javascript to add the title attribute to each `<option>` for this or all selects once the page has been loaded.